# Background image (watermark) with wicked-pdf

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, pdf, watermark, wicked-pdf

I need to use an image as a watermark on various documents I'm generating and converting to PDFs with wicked-pdf.  It took a while, but I have virtually everything working.  My show.pdf.erb is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head >
    <style type="text/css">
        <%= Rails.application.assets.find_asset('wicked.css').to_s.html_safe %>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class='wicked'>
    <div>
        <p><%= "#{Doc.last.contents} ".html_safe %></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My wicked.css is:

```
.wicked {
  background-image:url(/assets/test2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% -15%;
}
```

And my controller simply calls:

```
    render :pdf             => "test2",
        :formats        => [:pdf],
        :show_as_html       => true
```

All this works fine.  The watermark and the text pulled from the db present properly.  However, when I remove the "show_as_html" from the controller, the watermark disappears and only the text displays as a PDF.  Similarly, if I add "save_to_file", the file saves with only text and no watermark.  I'm baffled as to what I might be doing wrong.  I can't find any errors in any logs.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Hey, having trouble understanding what you are having trouble with?

Comment: The image disappears when I leave debugging mode and try to generate the pdf.

Comment: So the problem occurs when you go from development to production?

Comment: Correct.  To clarify, I'm remaining on the development server, but removing the wicked-pdf setting for debugging (show_as_html).  IOW, Rails.env = 'development'.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by using the SASS [asset-data-urlrelative-asset-path](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-data-urlrelative-asset-path), maybe you can use something like this:

```
background-image: asset-data-url('test2.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

This was solved in the WickedPdf Github issue tracker:

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/302

The basic issue here is that `url(/assets/test2.jpg)` is a relative path, when `WickedPdf` needs an absolute path, and the contents should be quoted like so:

```
url('file:///home/unconundrum/code/my_app/app/assets/images/test2.jpg')
```

Which can be done in a more portable way like this:

```
background-image:url('<%= "file://#{Rails.root.join('app','assets','images','test2.jpg')}" %>');
```

with an ERB stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue for my university application.
Solved as:

```
background-image: url("file://#{Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/marksheet-background.jpg')}");
```